# AddProximityAlert and Device wake up - Android

Tags: android

I have a problem. AddProximityAlert don' t want wake up my device. I don' t have any recivier(i can' t have in this situation, because can' t unregister it). I just push intent to addProximityIntent in this way:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(cxt, alarmView.class);
myIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);


PendingIntent proximityIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(cxt, records.get(pos).process,myIntent, 0);
locationManager.addProximityAlert(records.get(pos).x,
                            records.get(pos).y, records.get(pos).r, // metry
                            -1, proximityIntent);
```

I try to insert PowerManager.newWakeLock to myIntent.onCreate, but it doesn't work(i think because activity not created, before wake?).

**It is possilbe to give any parameters to my Intent to wake up my phone or do it in other way ?**

(If it possible i aslo want unlock device)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your onCreate() method in the `alarmView` activity, should be like :

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    /**** Turn the screen on and show your activity ****/
    android.view.Window window = getWindow();
    window.addFlags(android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
    window.addFlags(android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
    window.setContentView(R.layout.activity_alarm_view);
    /***************************************************/

    /**** Rest of your code as it is ****/

    /*  ---------------------------- ****/

    /************************************/
}
```

Here I assume the name of the layout file for this activity is `activity_alarm_view.xml`

Comment: It works, thanks :) But I still wonder why addProximityAlert don' t wake my device automatically, in documentation i read "In case the screen goes to sleep, checks for proximity alerts happen only once every 4 minutes", so should it wake it, because it check it state ?

Comment: @kolek : The documentation means that when the device is sleeping, the proximity alert checks still happen, but once every 4 minutes. For these checks to take place, it is not required that the device becomes fully awake; only the cpu needs to be awake so that the checks can be carried out. This conserves battery and at the same time ensures that the device can do proximity checks,location checks,process broadcast messages,etc.